# Not able to partition disk

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, mount

Why I am not able to partitin disk (button is grayed out)

It have 1 TB and I cant see full capacity.

[image]

I am also trying to restore it to its full capacity, but this command also done work.

`sudo diskutil eraseDisk FAT32 CleanDrive /dev/disk3#`

[image]

`Could not find disk for /dev/disk3#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>2</kbd>  [or View menu > Show All Devices] then format the entire device rather than just the volume.